# Figuring out name of result / theorem

Tags: discussion, self-answer

I had made a [question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3952297/revolving-chords-in-a-circle?noredirect=1#comment8149895_3952297) asking about a result mentioned in a book I was reading whose theorem I didn't know. One of the comments gave the right name of the theorem and proof, I posted that as a self answer to my question because I thought others would find it helpful. However, my answer is now deleted.

So, if one asks for a theorem without knowing its name what is the correct approach to answering such a question? Particularly when the theorem has a standard proof which can be found on the internet.

Comment: Your question was "How do I prove this theorem?", yet your answer was "The name of the theorem is [x], the proof can be found at [y]."  Such an answer is a kind of "link-only answer."  Such answers are not terribly useful, as they tend to suffer from link-rot.  A better answer would have actually given the proof.  In this case, I do not think that it was in appropriate to delete your answer.